# Substract data between two rows in same spark dataframe using Python

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am having a spark dataframe with two rows. This data frame contains both Numeric and String type values. I need to substract the numeric values of row2 from row1 while keeping the string values and column names same. This needs to be displayed in a new row in the same dataframe. I am using Spark Python for my code. Please help me

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question would be easier to understand if you could add some example data: your current data and the expected output. You also should add what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

scala

```
val df = Seq((5, "10"), (4, "fail_string")).toDF("a", "b")
val result = df.withColumn("result", $"b" - $"a")
result.show()
```

pyspark:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(5, "10"), (1, "fail")], "a int, b string")
result = df.withColumn("result", col("b") - col("a"))
result.show()
```

result will be:

```
+---+-----------+------+
|  a|          b|result|
+---+-----------+------+
|  5|         10|   5.0|
|  4|fail_string|  null|
+---+-----------+------+
```

as you can see that is a very simple spark use case and also safe to use without the fear of an exception if there are corrupt fields.

Comment: The above one column to column substraction but what I need is Row to Row

Comment: You are right I am sorry for that. But do you just have 2 rows? That kind of doesn't make sense in spark. is it maybe a DataFrame with 1 - n rows and you need to subtract all numeric columns e.g. like this row2 - row1, row3 - row2, row4 - row3, ... and so one?